# Деепричастие после прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, деепричастия

Имеется три варианта написания предложения. Какой вариант считается самым правильным, менее правильным и совсем неправильным?

> Вариант 1. "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись сказал он и мне все
>   стало с ним понятно.
>
> Вариант 2. "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он и мне все
>   стало с ним понятно.
>
> Вариант 3. "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись сказал он, и мне все
>   стало с ним понятно.

После того, как вы выберете вариант, скажите, изменится ли ситуация с пунктуацией в коротком варианте этого предложения.

> Вариант 4. "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись сказал он.
>
> Вариант 5. "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Я знаю, какую и когда мне галочку давать. Тут не тот пока вариант :-)

Comment: Денис, вижу, что вопрос обновлён. Но как же найти абсолютно параллельную конструкцию у классиков? Всё-таки: Вас интересуют обе проблемы - 1) одиночное деепричастие или оборот; 2) запятая в ССП, если одно из предложений имеет при себе прямую речь? Или одна, с запятой, разделяющей две основы?

Comment: Вопрос после обновления стал совершенно некорректным. Демарш в отношении общепризнанных правил русского языка - и предложение бонуса тому, кто этот демарш поддержит, не может быть признан допустимым. Поскольку автор защитился от закрытия назначением бонуса, рекомендую хотя бы заминусовать.

Comment: Если вы хотите ответить на свой вопрос, то вы вполне можете это сделать.

Comment: Тот редкий случай, когда действительно лучше проходить мимо, гражданин Мимоходов. Предложение закидывать камнями несогласных с системой могу давать лишь те, кто подливают, т.е. подлецы.

Answer (score 1):

"Менее" или "более" правильного не бывает; бывают факультативные или авторские знаки, но тут не тот случай.

Верен

> Вариант 5. "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он.

А из первых трёх всё какой-нибудь знак не на месте, но выбираем из 2 и 3:

> "Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он, и мне все стало с ним
>   понятно.

Это ССП, запятая перед ***и*** обязательна.

Ну а после ***рассердившись*** - обособляем деепричастие (нет причин его не обособлять).

---

После комментария "да ну?":

> – Я скажу тебе, какое это качество, – **рассердившись, сказала Тори**.
>   – Дом старый, построен около ста лет назад. И стоит до сих пор. Я бы
>   не стала сама проверять качество дерева на звук. Если ты хочешь его
>   купить, то, очевидно, должен пригласить специалистов.
>   Инженеров-строителей и архитекторов.

(Рэй Морган. [Прощай, мечта](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A0_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0/3))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[§ 70. Одиночные деепричастия](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=189)**

> обособляются при сохранении ими глагольного значения — обозначении
>   действия: *Не слезая с коня, она взяла пакет, размахнувшись, кинула
>   его в распахнутую дверь конюшни* (Улиц.); *Сначала и на машине
>   двигались со скоростью пешехода, то и дело царапали диффером и,
>   пятясь, объезжали камни* (Зал.); *Заскрежетав, закрылись двери*
>   (Вороб.).

**[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)**

Одиночное деепричастие обособляется, если сохраняет значение глагольности, выступая в функции второстепенного сказуемого, указывая на время действия, его причину, условие и т. д. (но не на образ действия): *Уходя, гасите свет*: (когда гаси́те?); *Казаки разъехались, не договорившись* (Ш.) — возможные вопросы: «когда разъехались?» *(после того как не договорились),* «почему разъехались?» *(потому что не договорились),* «вопреки чему разъехались?» *(хотя не договорились),* т. е. налицо или обстоятельство времени, или обстоятельство причины, или обстоятельство уступки, но только не обстоятельство образа действия (вопросы «как разъехались?» и «каким образом разъехались?» явно не подходят); *Пастух шёл, напевая, за стадом жадных и пугливых овец* (Т.) — ‘шел и напевал’; *Недалеко заухал филин, и Ласка, вздрогнув, стала прислушиваться* (Л. Т.) — ‘вздрогнула и стала прислушиваться’; *Отдохнув, он собирался уходить* (Фед.) — ‘после того как отдохнул’; *«Да, давно я уже не мылся», — говорил он, раздеваясь* (Ч.); *…Дед, кряхтя, влез в арбу* (М. Г.); *Мать, недоумевая, улыбалась* (М. Г.); *Довольные пассажиры, примолкнув, любовались солнечным днём* (Фед.); *За чертой, не всходя, томилось солнце* (Ш.); *Казаки сдержанно посматривали на него, расступаясь* (Ш.); *В этот момент от тоски и боли он обычно просыпался и долго лежал, отходя* (Гран.); *Он, улыбаясь, жмурился от света* (Щип.); *Да потеряешь время, бегая* — ‘если будешь бегать’; *Он поправил меня, смеясь; Задыхаясь, я перепрыгивал через канавы; Подходя, спросил Сергей; Она забегала по комнате, рассказывая; Наблюдая, удовлетворяешь свою любознательность; Соперничая, они старались превзойти один другого; Девушка, не раздумывая, повернула назад; Весело отвечал он, чокаясь; Морщась, он покосился на соседа; Скучая, слонялись они по улицам; Потом шаги их затихли, удаляясь; С усмешкой сказал он, интригуя; Вечером, засыпая, он смутно вспоминал события дня; Ползёт в гору, пыхтя, маленький паровозик; Не хвастая, расскажу о нашем походе; Она отвернулась, зарыдав; Рассказывая, он искоса поглядывал на присутствующих; Подумал он, насторожившись; Обжигаясь, пили горячий чай; Дети столпились кругом, любопытствуя; Под торжественные аккорды гимна в голубое небо, трепеща, взмывает флаг нашей страны; Он поскользнулся, упал и, чертыхаясь, с трудом встал на ноги; Ученик переспросил, не поняв; Играя, учись; Эти мосты неприятель взорвал, отступая; Не зная, и впрямь можно было поверить в это; По дороге, лая, бежала собака; Докладчик, отвернувшись, улыбнулся; Проводник, возвращаясь, стал махать рукой; Отвечайте, подумав; Он удивлённо посмотрел на всех, очнувшись; Он прервал свой рассказ, закуривая; Всё в природе, совершенствуясь, меняется; Бегут, озираясь, облака.*

Comment: Да ну? А можно примеры из литературы?

Comment: Примеры, посвящённые ССП или одиночному деепричастию, почему-то названному "оборотом"? Добавляю в ответ.

Comment: Галина, благодарю за дополнение, но меня интересует примеры выделение запятой перед "И", а не после деепричастия "рассердившись".

("Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он(!!!,!!!) и мне все стало с ним понятно.")

Comment: Перед *рассердившись* стоят запятая и тире - по правилам оформления прямой речи. В ССП запятая разделяет две основы: *сказал он* и *мне стало понятно*.

Comment: Я обновил свой пост

Answer (score 1):

**1) "Ты просто идиот", ― рассердившись, сказал он, и мне всё стало с ним понятно.**
Это сложносочиненное предложение, причем его первая часть включает прямую речь. Для связи предложений используется союз И. Запятая в ССП не ставится только при наличии общих элементов, которые здесь отсутствуют.

2) **"Ты просто идиот", ― рассердившись, сказал он.  Это предложение с прямой речью.**

**По поводу обособления деепричастия**

Деепричастие обычно  обозначает добавочное действие и обособляется,  но оно может переходить в наречие и тогда является необособленным обстоятельством образа действия.  Иногда приходится рассматривать парные варианты **с разной структурой**: Задумавшись, князь шёл по дороге. ― Князь шёл задумавшись.

Деепричастие **рассердившись** практически всегда обособляется (см. примеры из Нацкорпуса), но  **варианты без обособления всё-таки встречаются**, например: Держи ее, Петя! ― сказал рассердившись Лекарь-Аптекарь. ― Ну-ка. [В. А. Каверин. Много хороших людей и один завистник (1962)] В этом предложении возможны оба варианта (с обособлением и без обособления деепричастия).

[сказал рассердившись | ruscorpora.ru](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EA%E0%E7%E0%EB%20%F0%E0%F1%F1%E5%F0%E4%E8%E2%F8%E8%F1%FC)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Я думаю, что все проблемы при обсуждении этого вопроса возникли в связи с его неверной постановкой. Надо было обратить внимание отвечающих на то, что Вас в первую очередь интересует **необходимость обособления деепричастия.**

**2) Речь идет именно о деепричастии,** здесь нет деепричастного оборота.

3) **Возможные варианты предложения (без обособления):**

(1) "Ты просто идиот", – рассердИвшись сказал он, и мне все стало с ним понятно.

(2) "Ты просто идиот", – сердИто сказал он, и мне все стало с ним понятно.

(3)  "Ты просто идиот", – сказал он рассердИвшись, и мне все стало с ним понятно.

**Не хотите обособлять деепричастие**? Нет проблем, "тупые" правила разрешают Вам это сделать. **Но вот читатель (даже не редактор) может с Вами не согласиться** и элементарно сказать, что запятая пропущена. А почему?

Это предложение состоит из трех частей, и в конце каждой **мы обязаны обеспечить понижение тона** (повествовательная прямая речь, слова автора, второе предложение с точкой на конце).
   Теперь рассмотрим слова автора с возможными вариантами: **сказал он, тихо/сердито/ недовольно/рассердившись/недовольным голосом сказал он.** В зависимости от объёма этой  части мы ее делим или не делим на две фразы (повышение и понижение тона).  **В коротком предложении «сказал Он» повышения тона не делается, это одна фраза с пониженным тоническим ударением.** Если в предложение включено нераспространенное наречие небольшого объёма, то понижение голоса делается на нем, а остальная часть произносится ровным пониженным тоном:  тИхо сказал он. Это по-прежнему одна фраза.

**Но вот более объемное деепричастие «расссердившись» в эту схему вписывается уже хуже,** его удобнее выделить голосом и сделать паузу. Такое произношение звучит естественно, **и читать по-другому никто не будет** (дополнительно учитывая, что это деепричастие), если вы только какой-нибудь специальный знак не поставите. 
   Поэтому единственно правильное решение – это **изменение позиции деепричастия,** так как в конце предложения оно получит нужное выделение без обособления: **сказал он рассердИвшись.**

Так что правила русской пунктуации – это отличный инструмент в умелых руках, если автор не только знает эти правила, но и понимает интонационно-структурный принцип постановки знаков препинания.

5) К прямой речи и к сложному предложению эта проблема, как я думаю,  отношения не имеет.

Comment: Я обновил свой пост

Comment: @Arina *Нет проблем, "тупые" правила разрешают* - Ну что вы в самом деле, уговариваете, прямо как маленького. Какие правила, если автор считаете "деепричастным оборотом" всё предложение, первую часть ССП ("Рассердившись сказал он") - и на этом основании опускает запятую?! И про "тупые правила" вы напрасно. Там очень строго оговорено, когда одиночное причастие может быть обстоятельством образа действия (т.е. собственным членом предложения) членом предложения. Здесь - никак, уже сам по себе совершенный вид сильно мешает. На этом основании опустить запятую может только очень упертый автор.

Answer (score 0):

В "коротком" варианте оба правильные, но #5 - "более правильный". Одиночное причастие можно рассматривать как обстоятельство образа действия (в "адаптированных" источниках называют "оттенком действия") и на этом основании не обособлять ([Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)), но в нашем случае это будет весьма сомнительно, "рассердившись" здесь скорее всего самостоятельное действие.

С этих же позиций надо разбирать и исходный случай. Одиночное деепричастие здесь требует обособления, а уж оснований опустить запятую между двумя составляющими сложносочиненного предложения совсем не просматривается.

Я за "четвертый" вариант, у вас отсутствующий, с двумя запятыми.
***"Ты просто идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он, и мне все стало с ним понятно.***
Но если вы ставите вопрос ребром, какой **из трех** "самый правильный", то только третий. Отсутствие запятую после деепричастия я еще как-то могу обосновать (пусть и слабо), но никак не той, что перед союзом "И".

Вообще вопрос не совсем удачно поставлен. Никаких особенностей в оформлении деепричастия именно после прямой речи и нет, все стандартно, если не считать, конечно, того факта, что запятая **после** тире в принципе не ставится никогда.

> но меня интересует примеры выделение запятой перед "И"

А это запятая не для "выделения", а для разделения. Эта **разделяющая** запятая регулярно ставится между частями ССП. Есть изъятия из этого правила, но прямая речь и/или деепричастие тут совершенно ни при чем.

> Мне нужны хотя бы три примера из классической и современной
>   литературы, где бы показывалось наличие запятой после местоимения "ОН"
>   в указанном примере (дополнительно выделяю в скобках) "Ты просто
>   идиот", - рассердившись, сказал он(,) и мне все стало с ним понятно.

Мне непонятна такая постановка. Слово ОН тут ни при чем, а если без него, то примеров сколько угодно.

> 1. Запятыми разделяются части сложносочиненного предложения, между 
>      которыми стоят союзы:
>      1)      соединительные: и, да (в значении «и»), ни... ни. Например:
>      Все лица нахмурились, и в тишине слышалось сердитое кряхтенье и
>      покашливание Кутузова (Л. Толстой); Дикие и даже страшные в своем
>      величии горы выступали резко из тумана, да вдали тянулась едва
>      заметная белая струйка дыма (Короленко); Ни калина не растет между
>      ними [крестами], ни трава не зеленеет... (Гоголь);

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm) "СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ"

Comment: Я обновил свой пост

Comment: @ДенисФедоров а я его заминусовал. Чтоб неповадно было синтаксический нигилизм проповедовать.

Answer (score 0):

Три литературных примера с запятой после "он" (похожих на "сказал он, и мне все стало с ним понятно"):

*– Девочка, Катенька, – ласково **произнес он, и стало сразу понятно**, как сильно любит он свою Катеньку.*
[**А. Маринина. Убийца поневоле**](http://knijky.ru/books/ubiyca-ponevole?page=10)

*— О твоем ненаглядном дядюшке Мэйконе, — **произнесла она** озлобленно, **и мне стало понятно**, что Сарафина не простила, что Мэйкон отнял у нее дочь.*
[**М. Штоль. Прекрасные создания**](http://www.rulit.me/books/prekrasnye-sozdaniya-read-220223-170.html)

*По дороге **я наблюдала** за сестрой, за коричневой спиной в топе с лямкой вокруг шеи, за сгорбленными плечами, **и мне стало ясно**, что для нее все изменилось, даже если она еще этого не знает.*
[**Д. Мойес. До встречи с тобой**](http://knijky.ru/books/do-vstrechi-s-toboy?page=173)

**Дополнение**

Собственно, о деепричастии после прямой речи:

*— Ты держалась безупречно, — **обернувшись**, произнес он.*
М. Андерсон. Пятьдесят оттенков темного

*— Спасибо, — **улыбаясь**, произнес Гарри, отбрасывая назад мокрые от пота волосы.*
Д. К. Роулинг. Гарри Поттер и философский камень

*— Я почему-то именно так и подумала, — **кивнув**, произнесла она.*
К. Муравьев. Подготовка

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вопрос стоял о запятой перед "и", поэтому мне и хотелось её выделить, а это невозможно сделать без пробела. Или есть тонкости, про  которые я не знаю?

Comment: Я так и понял, но уж очень пробел плохо смотрится. Тем не менее это Ваше право, так что простите, что нарушил Ваш замысел! Вернёте сами, как было, если всё-таки хотите, чтобы так осталось? Или скажите, и я верну. Простите ещё раз!

Comment: Я бы сам так не стал делать из-за того, что так очень некрасиво, и потому, что, даже если на запятую не выделять, её всё равно не должны обойти вниманием, п. ч. о ней вопрос. Но не пытаюсь Вас переубедить. Просто высказал свои мысли. :)

Comment: Нет-нет, какие там извинения!  _Вполне_ доверяю Вам ( как более опытному участнику), Вашему мнению и восприятию.

Comment: Спасибо большое за доверие, Римма!))